# Jquery form plugin not showing success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqueryform

I have this code:

```
$(".myform").live('submit', function(e){   
    var options = { 
        target: '.ajaxMessage',
        // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
        beforeSubmit:  showRequest,
        success: function(data) {   
            alert(data);
            //$('#dialog-confirm').dialog('close');
            //$(".ajaxMessage").html(data).show().delay('5000').fadeOut("5000");
        },
        type: 'POST'
```

`$(".myform").ajaxForm(options);`

The firefox console is showing this as response

```
Response

1{"code":"OK"}
```

My data gets inserted in database correctly but i am not able to call that success function also in Firefox console i get the desired response with success message template,

Comment: `$.live()` is deprecated. Just so you know. Use `$.on()` or `$.delegate()` instead.

Comment: but website says that live should still work

Comment: "deprecated" `!=` "does not work". In this case, it means *try something else because soon it won't be available*.

Comment: Thats because you normally can't call the `success` method, its a callback... When the config is properly pushed to a new XHR instance, that instance is in charge of firing the `success` method based on a 200 type response.

Comment: so what should i do , any code that can do the trick

Comment: You need to show more of your code. How are you using the `options` object (and where is the rest of it)?

Comment: At least you should show the end of `.live`.

Comment: i tried on , it didn't worked, but live worked

Comment: add error call back just in case the server side returning error instead of sucess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and share some more of your code or use JsFiddle for code sharing, anywayz on my assumption i am sharing the code, hope it works for ya:

```
$(".myform").on('submit', function(e){   
    var options = { 
        target: '.ajaxMessage',
        // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
        beforeSubmit:  showRequest,
        success: function(data) {   
            alert(data);
            //$('#dialog-confirm').dialog('close');
            //$(".ajaxMessage").html(data).show().delay('5000').fadeOut("5000");
        },
        error: function(){
        alert('Error!!!')
        },
        type: 'POST'
    }
});
```